# Parsing bitcoin address in html

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup, bitcoin

I'm trying to use the beautiful soup lib to parse a webpage and find bitcoin addresses.

I've managed to pull the class containing a generated address out of the whole html document:

```
<div class="roundpic qrcode" data-height="80" data-text="bitcoin:1JL7kugm1vDLqyzrVPAPdcbjH3PTxcPcud?amount=0.0573" data-width="80" style="margin: auto"></div>, <div class="roundpic qrcode" data-height="160" data-text="bitcoin:1JL7kugm1vDLqyzrVPAPdcbjH3PTxcPcud?amount=0.0573" data-width="160" style="padding: 10px"></div>
```

What would be the best way to isolate the address? I know the length can be between 27-34 characters but it will always appear in between 'bitcoin:' and '?'. Is there a regex I could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a regex. Basic string operations work just fine:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="roundpic qrcode" data-height="80" data-text="bitcoin:1JL7kugm1vDLqyzrVPAPdcbjH3PTxcPcud?amount=0.0573" data-width="80" style="margin: auto"></div>
<div class="roundpic qrcode" data-height="160" data-text="bitcoin:1JL7kugm1vDLqyzrVPAPdcbjH3PTxcPcud?amount=0.0573" data-width="160" style="padding: 10px"></div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for div in soup.find_all('div', {'data-text': re.compile(r'^bitcoin:')}):
    address, amount = div.get('data-text').replace('bitcoin:', '').split('?amount=')
```

`soup.find_all('div', {'data-text': re.compile(r'^bitcoin:')})` finds all `<div>` elements where the `data-text` attribute's value starts with `bitcoin:`. You could have also used:

```
soup.find_all('div', {'data-text': lambda value: value.startswith('bitcoin:')})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy using [python regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re
in_str=<div class="roundpic qrcode" data-height="80" data-text="bitcoin:1JL7kugm1vDLqyzrVPAPdcbjH3PTxcPcud?amount=0.0573" data-width="80" style="margin: auto"></div>, <div class="roundpic qrcode" data-height="160" data-text="bitcoin:1JL7kugm1vDLqyzrVPAPdcbjH3PTxcPcud?amount=0.0573" data-width="160" style="padding: 10px"></div>
bitcoin_addresses=re.findall(r'bitcoin:(.*?)\?amount',in_str)
```

The one thing that's might be confusing is that ? is a special character in regular expressions, but you are also trying to match it. You need to use *? to perform lazy matching, and then \? to actually match the ?. The backslash is an escape character that says "I don't mean the special character ?, I mean an actual question mark."

Comment: But, if you are already using beautifulsoup, then go with Blender's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, back in the days you could have used regex to do that. However, regex is not meant for parsing. As you have already parsed the DOM anyway, why don't you access it directly? :)

```
# imports
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

# parse the HTML
s = Soup("<html><body><div data-text='bitcoin:a'></div><div data-text='bitcoin:b'></div><div data-text='bitcoin:c'></div></body></html>")

# find the divs with "data-text"-attribute
divs = ( d for d in s.findAll(name="div") if d.has_key('data-text') )

# extract the value of "data-text"
data_texts = map(lambda x: x["data-text"], divs)

# find only bitcoins
bitcoins = filter(lambda s: s.startswith("bitcoin:"), data_texts)

# strip the prefix
extract = map(lambda s: s[8:], bitcoins)

# result
print extract
```

Result:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Hope, this was helpful.

Cheers!

//EDIT:
Blender's answer makes use of regex within BeautifulSoup. Although this is neat, you can leave out the regex completely by simply postfiltering!

This also makes use of generator pipelining, which is really powerful. [David Beazley on Generators](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf)